# Window style not being applied when DataTemplate build dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, styles

I have a ResourceDictionary that contains Style definitions for controls used within my application.

All of the styles are applied properly to the controls in the window.

In one specific case, I need to build DataTemplate and Grid dynamically by code (in code behind). When my control is display, all items and data are correctly displayed but, it's seems that Style are not applied. When I clicked on border of my screen to resize, the Style is applied at this specific moment.

Why? And what can I do to applied Style when control is displayed?

**EDIT**
Here's my Xaml:

```
<Common:MyPopUpWindow 
  ...
  ...
  >
   <Common:MyPopUpWindow.DataContext>
      <Controls:DynamicPicklistControlViewModel/>
   </Common:MyPopUpWindow.DataContext>
   <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Margin="2" Behaviours:ToolbakKeyBehaviour.IsEnabled="True">
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
         <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>

      <Grid x:Name="grdPicklist">
         <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
         </Grid.RowDefinitions>

         <Common:MyBlockListBox x:Name="lbxPicklist" 
                                Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="99" />
      </Grid>
      <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
         ...
         ...
      </StackPanel>
   </Grid>
</Common:MyPopUpWindow  >
```

And this is my code behind:

```
  private void OnShowPicklist(DynamicPicklistControlViewModel.ShowPicklistMessage obj)
  {
     if (!IsVisible)
     {
        CreateDataTemplate(obj.ColumnSpecs);
        CreateGridLayout(obj.ColumnSpecs);
        ShowDialog();
     }
  }

  private void CreateDataTemplate(IEnumerable<AdmPicklistColSpec> columnSpecs)
  {
     var xaml = new StringBuilder();

     xaml.AppendLine("<ResourceDictionary xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation' ");
     xaml.AppendLine("                    xmlns:x='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml' ");
     xaml.AppendLine("                    xmlns:Common='clr-namespace:Xxx.Xxxxxxxxxx.Xxx.Xxxx.Client.Common'>");
     xaml.AppendLine("");
     xaml.AppendLine("   <DataTemplate x:Key='dtplPicklist'>");
     xaml.AppendLine("      <Grid x:Name='grdPicklist'>");
     xaml.AppendLine("         <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>");

     for (var i = 0; i < columnSpecs.Count(); i++)
     {
        xaml.AppendLine("            <ColumnDefinition Width='*'/>");
     }

     xaml.AppendLine("         </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>");
     xaml.AppendLine("         <Grid.RowDefinitions>");
     xaml.AppendLine("            <RowDefinition Height='{StaticResource DefaultListBoxItemHeight}' />");
     xaml.AppendLine("         </Grid.RowDefinitions>");
     xaml.AppendLine("");

     var iCol = 0;
     foreach (var colSpec in columnSpecs)
     {
        xaml.AppendLine("         <Common:MyFormTextBox x:Name='txtCol" + colSpec.DisplaySeqNbr + "' ");
        xaml.AppendLine("                                    Grid.Column='" + iCol + "' ");
        xaml.AppendLine("                                    Text='{Binding Path=Col" + colSpec.DisplaySeqNbr + "}' />");

        iCol++;
     }

     xaml.AppendLine("      </Grid>");
     xaml.AppendLine("   </DataTemplate>");
     xaml.AppendLine("</ResourceDictionary>");

     var xamlParse = (ResourceDictionary)XamlReader.Parse(xaml.ToString());
     foreach (var key in xamlParse.Keys)
     {
        Resources.Add(key, xamlParse[key]);
     }
  }

  private void CreateGridLayout(IEnumerable<AdmPicklistColSpec> columnSpecs)
  {
     var grid = grdPicklist;

     if (_multiplePicklist)
        grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto) });

     // <ColumnDefinition>
     for (var i = 0; i < columnSpecs.Count(); i++)
     {
        var colDef = new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) };
        grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(colDef);
     }
     // Adding extra column for scrollbar
     grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = (GridLength)Application.Current.Resources["DefaultListBoxScrollBarWidth"] });
     // </ColumnDefinition>

     // Defines Labels
     var iCol = 0;
     foreach (var label in columnSpecs.Select(colSpec => new MyStackLabel { Content = colSpec.LabelTxt }))
     {
        Grid.SetRow(label, 0);
        Grid.SetColumn(label, iCol);
        grid.Children.Add(label);
        iCol++;
     }

     // Block list box
     lbxPicklist.ItemTemplate = Resources["dtplPicklist"] as DataTemplate;
     lbxPicklist.SetBinding(MyBlockListBox.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding("Items"));
     var colSpan = columnSpecs.Count() + 1;
     Grid.SetColumnSpan(lbxPicklist, colSpan);
  }
```

Comment: Solution: do not create WPF UI elements in code.

Comment: Have you tried first adding the Grid to the window (in the code behind) and after that setting the ItemsSource?

Comment: Adding an small example that reproduces the problem would probably be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed to problem by setting the property `SizeToContent` to `Manual` instead of `WidthAndHeight` and specified a `Width` and `Height` in my Xaml.